# NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null (Flutter Web)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am making a Card list that gets data from a Firestore database for a Flutter Web application, but this error is thrown:

```
 - "The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building
   UserList(dirty, dependencies: [InheritedProvider<List<ClientUser>>],
   state: _UserListState#ab779): NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on
   null: 'length'"
```

Here is the code that I am using to build the list:

```dart
class _UserListState extends State<UserList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final users = Provider.of<List<ClientUser>>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return UserTile(user: users[index]);
      },
      itemCount: users.length,
    );
  }
```

In my database service file, here is how I get the snapshot from the database and get the list from the snapshot:

```dart
List<ClientUser> _clientListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
    return ClientUser(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '', difficulty: doc.data['difficulty'] ?? 5);
  }).toList();
}

// get users stream
Stream<List<ClientUser>> get users {
  return userCollection.snapshots().map(_clientListFromSnapshot);
}
```

Here is how I declare the StreamProvider:

```dart
return StreamProvider<List<ClientUser>>.value(
      value: UserDatabaseService().users,
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Did you try adding a null check on users before returning the `ListView.builder`?

Comment: You will need to check your return from database, to verify if it's null. By the error, Flutter is indicating that you are working with null values. As @ShubhamGupta mentioned, please, add a exception treatment to your code, to verify better the error.

Comment: thank y'all! the null check worked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001207/flutter-cloud-firestore-unknown-nosuchmethoderror-invalid-member-on-null-i

Comment: Use this link  which can be helpful

Answer (score 3):

As previously mentioned in the comments, it's likely that checking the values of an empty List causes the error. A simple null checker should fix the issue.

```dart
final users = Provider.of<List<ClientUser>>(context);
if (users != null && users.length > 0){
  return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return UserTile(user: users[index]);
    },
    itemCount: users.length,
  );
}
else {
  // Display loading widget
  
}
```