# Flutter :[cloud_firestore/unknown] NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges' (Flutter Web)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-widget

I am trying to fetch data from Friebase-firestore and then convert it to model, I used the same code and approach to another project (web project) ,it works fine , but with this project it doesn't work ,I don't know why. I upgrade flutter version, run Flutter doctor , and nothing wrong with the environment setup.
here is the code :

```
class dbService{

static final CollectionReference myCollection = 
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection');

static Future<myModel> getMyInfo() async{
myModel sanaa ;
print('this line to print');
final QuerySnapshot myInfo =await myCollection.limit(1).get();
myInfo.docs.forEach((element) {
  print(element.data()['name']);
 sanaa= new myModel(
      name:element.data()['name'].toString(),
      title: element.data()["title"].toString(),
      img: element.data()['img'].toString(),
     );
  print('\n print  ------ ');
  print(element.data()['name']);
  print('   that is');
}

);
return sanaa;

}
}
class dbManager{
 Stream<myModel> myInfoStream() async*{
 yield await dbService.getMyInfo();
 }
}
   class _aboutStateState extends State<aboutState> { 
   Stream stream ;
   dbManager mng = new dbManager();
  @override
   void initState() {
   // TODO: implement initState
    stream = mng.myInfoStream();
    super.initState();
   }
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    color: Colors.pink[300],
    child: StreamBuilder<myModel>(
     stream: stream,
     builder: (context, snapshot){
       if(snapshot.hasError){
         print(snapshot.error);
        return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong , please try again later'),);
      }
      else if(snapshot.hasData){
  
        return  Text("${snapshot.data.name}");
      
      }
      else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
  ),
```

I got this error

```
this line to print
[cloud_firestore/unknown] NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges'
```

but when I connect directly to the firestore without converting it into model ,It works fine and print the data in the screen , the code :

```
child:FutureBuilder(
   future: me.doc(id).get(),
    
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      if(snapshot.hasError){
        print(snapshot.error);
        return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong , please try again later'),);
      }
      else if(snapshot.hasData){
       // print("${snapshot.data.data()['app_pics'][1]}  \n${snapshot.data.data()['img']}");
        return  Text("${snapshot.data.data()['app_pics'][1]}");
        
      }
      else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
  ),
```

I run flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale
  en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.51.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Please I need help
[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found the answer, it caused because of the version of Firebase JS SDK .
I replace 8.1.1 to 7.22.1 in index.html file

```
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <!--  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>-->

<!--  &lt;!&ndash; TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use-->
<!--       https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries &ndash;&gt;- ->
<!--  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"> 
</script>-->
 <!--  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>-->
```

I am using 7.22.1 version for **Firebase JS SDK**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

Comment: Google recommend 8.1.1, but only this works

Comment: @DheerajSarwaiya Yes that's right, I don't know why 8.1.1 doesn't work

Comment: The curse of working with new tech! Anyway thank you so much for this!!

Comment: Only firestore has issues I guess, I am using v7.22.1 for firestore and v8.2.3 for rest

Comment: @SumitSahoo , Uh ok, I really don't know what is the problem, but when I changed it started working fine .. thanks

Comment: Yes, I am also wondering why the new version not working. But hey when you are short on time quick fix is all you want. But I think this needs to be investigated though :)

Comment: @SumitSahoo , I agree with you :)

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to set my pubspec.yml dependencies to exactly what you have in your original question ( firebase_core: ^0.5.2+1   ;    cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1 )

Comment: @RiversCuomo .. Happy that is working  , hope they solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can also use 8.0.1 as mentioned here and subscribe to the issue. Then you get (hopefully) notified once it´s fixed.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4127#issuecomment-754171740

Answer (score 1):

Try out this **versions**:

```html
firebase_core: ^0.5.2
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3
```

For more info check out this github [Link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4127)

Comment: I changed the dependencies ,the same error appear.. I don't know why

Comment: Did you reinstall app or just restarting ?

Comment: Yes, but it's web app, not mobile app

Comment: @A R I found the answer, It was because the version of Firebase JS SDK in the index.html file ,I replace 8.1.1 with 7.22.1 .. check the answer below ... and thanks a lot for the help